# Unable to get holes in centre of object

Tags: modifiers

Not sure if this is an issue of non-volume geometry, but I'm trying to get holes in the centre of my object (film reel)and when I use a second boolean modifier in the plane object to difference of circle.001 it makes the entire reel disappear.

[image]

[image: Circle.001 settings (the cylinders in the centre of the reel)]

[image: Plane settings]

Comment: please write your questions so that they are not dependent on people inspecting your file only. Add images adn other descriptions that might illustrate the issue you are having. As I've mentioned before pasteall.org has a time limit on how long they make the files available. After that period your links will disappear and other users won't be able to download your files anymore and the question won't be useful to others in the future. Please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ – cegaton Nov 5 at 15:33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the object you are using to cut the boolean is a mess... it is made out of a lot of overlapping surfaces.

[image]

Bolleans don't like that kind of geometry...

If you use a regular cylinder to cut the boolean everything works fine

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Cegaton!  I appreciate it.  I had actually tried to cap hollow cylinders which must be where I went wrong.  Didn't think to just start over again with fresh capped cylinders.

Comment: @lakerice You had the most convoluted way of making a cylinder that I have ever seen ;-)

Comment: Damn youtube tutorials...

Comment: @lakerice if the answers work for you remember to mark them as accepted. please read http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer and http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour